# Renaming column in Pandas doesn't do anything

Tags: python, pandas

I'm importing a CSV file which has the following header(column names):

```
"Appendix","Name / Organization","Issuer","Algorithm"
```

I tried changing the "Appendix" column name into "Other Info" but it doesn't work.

```
df.rename(columns={'Appendix':'Other Info'}, 
                 inplace=True)
```

I get no error and when I print the dataframe again, it looks like the original one. (nothing has changed). I don't understand why. Can you give me an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: can you try `df.columns = df.rename(columns={'Appendix':'Other Info'})` ditch the inplace, it's best not to use it.

Comment: Check the output of `df.columns`. There could be `whitespaces` in your column headers. You would need to handle those in rename command as well.

Comment: Index(['"Appendix","Name / Organization","Issuer","Algorithm"'], dtype='object'). Therefore, no whitespaces...

Comment: i see a additional quotation mark `'"Appendix"`

Answer (score 1):

Some methods to sort this out:

1. Restart the kernel and run again.
2. If it doesn't help, assign a list of new column names

   df.columns = ['Other Info' , 'Name / Organization' , 'Issuer' , 'Algorithm']
3. Create a new column `Other Info`, copy all the data from `Appendix` and drop your `Appendix` column

Answer (score 1):

make sure column name doesn't have any invisible characters line space and'\n'. The key u give in `df.replace` function should match the column name.

try theese

```
    df.rename(columns={'df.columns[0]':'Other Info'}, 
             inplace=True)
```

or

```
    df.columns=["Other info","Name / Organization","Issuer","Algorithm"]
```

Comment: '\n' can appear in groupby operations of Pandas for the new column names. It is better to do an assignation after aggregation operations.